# ray tracing shadow bug

Tags: c++, graphics, raytracing

[image: Comparison]

http://pastebin.com/vkTJt0sT

I am trying to render an image similiar to the left one and having problem with shadows+reflections.

Right now, only the shadow code is open for showing the problem.

As you can see, the red ball should be shadowed near the green one, but the pixels all get messed up for some weird reason. When I close the shadow part of the code, it renders the red ball normally without shadows.

I think the root of this problem is also affecting reflections. hope you guys can give me some tips; I’m losing it.

Comment: You should generally include your code directly in your post (and cut it down to something smaller if at all possible) instead of linking to external sites.

Comment: Make sure you're not actually self shadowing. I've written something similar before and the ray was intersecting with the surface it was leaving, I fixed it by moving the intersection point slightly in the direction of the outgoing ray (away from the surface).

Comment: couldnt manage to post the code inside so i linked it out :/

Comment: How "slightly"? I tried a it a little and the result is either no shadow at all or its the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that your left image shows *cancer*, this is a classic case of the shadow ray hitting the object off which it was reflected.  When hit-testing a shadow ray, you need to exclude the surface that generated the ray.  Just pass the source object into your shadow function, and ignore it.

This method only works for convex shapes.  If you have shapes that do self-shadow (a torus, for example), you need to be more general.  The usual approach is to define an *epsilon* (floating-point error tolerance) and ignore any intersection points that are nearer than that.

The other approach is to detect which *side* of a surface you hit.  You should not self-shadow on a sphere because the ray is being cast in the same general direction as the surface normal (*ie* the dot product of the outgoing ray and the surface normal is positive) - this should not be counted as a shadow.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
There was an algorithmic problem which isn't easy to explain,

Another method is: Basicly I make a check if the cosine angle is bigger than 0.0001, if it is bigger then this I don't shadow it